How to Mock a Function Within a FastAPI Route Using Pytest
I'm working on a FastAPI application and am trying to write some tests for one of my routes. My testing environment cannot make calls to external services. My goal is just to test the parsing of the service's response, creation of log data, etc. The route I am testing calls a function that interacts with the external service, and I want to mock this function to return a predefined response. I've tried using pytest's monkeypatching, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Here is my project structure:
root
├── routes
│   └── my_route.py
├── services
│   └── my_service.py
├── tests
│   └── test_routes_mocked.py
└── main.py

FastAPI App (main.py)
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(title="API", docs_url="/")

app.include_router(my_route.router)

FastAPI Route (routes/my_route.py)
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from models import MyRequestModel, MyResponseModel
from services.my_service import process_request

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/process", response_model=MyResponseModel)
async def my_route(request: MyRequestModel):
    response = await process_request(request)
    # Other logic here that parses the response and builds a response object
    return parsed_response

Function to be Mocked (services/my_service.py)
async def process_request(request: MyRequestModel):
    # This function returns the call to the external service
    result = external_service_call(request)
    return result

Test Case (tests/test_routes_mocked.py)
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app
from services.my_service import process_request

client = TestClient(app)

mock_response_data = {
    "data": "mocked response"
}

@pytest.fixture
def mock_process_request(monkeypatch):
    async def mock_process(request):
        return mock_response_data

    monkeypatch.setattr("services.my_service.process_request", mock_process)

def test_my_route(mock_process_request):
    request_data = {
        "param1": "value1"
    }

    response = client.post("/process", json=request_data)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == mock_response_data

When I run the test, the process_request function is not being mocked correctly and the original function is still being called. I am wondering how can I properly mock the process_request function within my FastAPI route?I basically just want to override a single function's response, just for testing. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
I also tried using unittest.mock to patch the function, but that did not seem to work either

You should try to create a fixture that provide the test client.
If you import you app in the fixture, the client will be created at the runtime, instead of during the pytest test collection.
Try this instead:
@pytest.fixture()
def get_client():
    from main import app

    yield TestClient(app)

# I never used the pytest monkeypatch fixture, so I do an example with mock.patch, but I guess it should work in your way
@patch("services.my_service.process_request")
def test_my_route(process_request: Mock, get_client):
    process_request.return_value = {"data": "mocked response"}
    request_data = {"param1": "value1"}
    response = get_client.post("/process", json=request_data)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == mock_response_data



I tried to mock with test_client and mocker without success.
test_client seems to use the original version completely ignoring my mock.
In the end, I override the view_function to make this work. I could not find a better solution so far.
By the way, you would do yourself a favor by simplifying the test case as much as possible.
main.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

test_route.py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def client(mocker):
    """When a test_client is created, it ignores mocks and seems to copy the original code.
    Therefore, we substitute the view_function directly.
    """
    # Import app after the mock is set
    from src.flask_test.main import app

    # Set up test client and app context
    with app.test_client() as client, app.app_context():
        client.application.view_functions["home"] = mocker.Mock(
            return_value="Hello, Dude!"
        )
        yield client


def test_myroute(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.data == b"Hello, Dude!"



Its for Flask, not for Fastapi
